# After Dual-Boot Win10/Ubuntu 14.04 Can't boot windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS parallel with Windows 10. After installing and rebooting, the grab window appears correctly and I have 2 option for booting from windows and one option for boot from Linux.

When I choose to boot from Linux everything's fine.

**When I try to boot from windows nothing happens**.

When I choose the first option **"sda1"** it redirects me in a **black window** with a flashing underscore.

When  I choose the second option **"sda2"** it redirects me again in the grab window to **select again an OS**.

I tried boot-repair but no result. What should I do?

Comment: Did  you turn off fast start up in Windows? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 0):

use windows repair disc or windows installation disc to repair boot of windows 10.

then, boot into a ubuntu live disc and recover grub with boot-repair.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair